# How to use HTTP GET request using c++ and clean code?

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, visual-studio-2015

I need to connect a c++ console app with a website and retrieve the html page. I use this code:

```
int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.giallozafferano.it");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    cout << "Connecting...\n";
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0) {
        cout << "Could not connect";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Connected.\n";
    send(Socket, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.giallozafferano.it/ricerca-ricette/pasta/\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.giallozafferano.it/ricerca-ricette/pasta/\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"), 0);
    char buffer[10000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {         
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    string page(buffer);
    page = page.erase(page.size()-1);

    cout << endl << page << endl;

    size_t found = page.find("<Risultati Ricerca");
    if (found != std::string::npos) {
        cout << "risultati found at position: " << found << '\n';
    }

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

it works but the result of the site is different every time that I connect to the site... Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting root/home page (GET /) of the host. Probably is not a static page but a dynamic build one.

Note: you probably want to turn

```
GET /
```

into

```
GET /ricerca-ricette/pasta/
```

and as Host place simply www.giallozafferano.it

Then put all in one variable and use strlen, tyo avoid mistakes in duplicating manually the string.

Comment: I think no, however thanks a lot... but it worked for 5 times and now it doesn't work again... do you know what? .. sorry for the question again @marom

Comment: If you have a linux box try compare the output of your program with wget's output. Or google for "wget for windows" there is a gnu version

Comment: I resolved... I needed to delete the _**/**_ after **pasta** @marom